# 1999 4 Cylinder Gas Tank Box With multiple connectors

Tags: toyota, suspension, camry, fuel-tank, rear

Hi I am replacing rear suspension components on my **1999 4 Cylinder LE Toyota Camry** and realized that Toyota engineered this model's undercarriage in a way to charge consumers more for PARTS & LABOR because in order for the  `Rear FORWARD Lower/Adjustable Lateral Control Arm` to properly be removed about via its 7-8" long 19mm bolt that connects through to the `Rear REARWARD Lower/Adjustable Lateral Control Arm` more clearance is needed than the inch given with the **Gas Tank** Installed.

During The Gas Tank removal I noticed that there was a `Plastic Box With Several Connectors and Ports` hidden in above the `Anti-Sway/Roll Bar` AND `Rear FORWARD Lower/Adjustable Lateral Control Arm`.... I Found some plastic hoses that were hanging and ripped just dangling upon further inspection and some electrical wires and connectors as well. I went through my old Chilton Manual for this model but I could not find information on this component...can anyone please explain:

a. ***What this is ?***

b. ***Its purpose ?***

c. ***How many connections run through it***

d. ***Any other pertinent information related to this Plastic Box***

e. ***Point me to some links, videos, websites I can learn from please and thank you.***

I have attached Pictures of this Plastic Box with connectors below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Its part of the evaporative emissions system

Comment: How long has the check engine light been on showing evap leak large code?